# Getting a correct full screen camera in chrome tools but getting smaller screen in real devices

Tags: javascript, camera, progressive-web-apps, getusermedia, mediadevices

I am making a PWA which uses the camera of the device. I am getting a correct full-screen camera in chrome tools but getting a smaller screen in real devices. I have tried setting width and height like this but that didn't fix the error:

```
width: { min: 640, ideal: 1920, max: 1920 },
height: { min: 400, ideal: 1080 },
```

A fixed width and height values solved the problem for a particular device but not for all the devices.

Constraints passed

[image]

```
var constraints = {};

if(front===false){
    constraints = { video: {facingMode:  "environment",width: (window.screen.availWidth),
        height: (window.screen.availHeight) },frameRate: {max : 60},aspectRatio:1.777777778} ;
    console.log("Running rear camera");
}
else{
    constraints = { video: {facingMode: "user", width: (window.screen.availWidth),
        height: (window.screen.availHeight) },frameRate: {max : 60},aspectRatio:1.777777778} ;
    console.log("Running front camera.");
}

 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(function (stream) {
        window.stream = stream;

        videoPlayer.srcObject = stream;

    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

[image]
[image]

Image *Left* <--: Full screen in Chrome DevTools

Image *Right* -->: Camera isn't full-screen on real devices

**Take a look at the demo code here:**
 https://github.com/NischalJakhar/NischalJakhar.github.io

Comment: Have you tried checking the [Take Photos and Control Camera Settings](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/imagecapture) ?

Comment: @noogui I read this documentaion. It improved the image quality of captured image and some added camera features but the problem remains.